# Which programming language to use for data processing on a server?

Tags: mysql, data-processing

I am planning to start a project where a client uses a form to enter data which is forwarded to a MySQL database. From this database the data should be read by a script which is processing the data (comparision with other values stored in another database and some mathematical operations). After that the result should be send to the user via email.
My question how to do this data processing the best.
I think that I need a script running all the time which is scanning for new queries. But I don't know which programming language works best for this case and whether there is anything specific I have to consider for the server / database setup.

I hope that my questions are clear and would love to get an answer on my questions.

Thanks in advance!
Tim

Comment: It depends on your resources as well. Are you using a Linux server or a windows one?

Comment: Will use a Linux server because I mainly work with them

Answer (score 2):

First, you should consider programming languages you know and can be proficient in.

Second, you should consider which of those programming languages are likely to be maintained for the lifetime of your project.

Third, you should consider which of those programming languages you can hire for when your project becomes successful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I mainly work with java and c# so maybe one of these can be used for the project. They're also pretty common so hiring would be possible I think.